# Extract a string using regular expressions

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, string-matching

I'm probably not using the right search term, because I keep finding

'matching\validating' string with regex (returns boolean) while I want is to extract a string from an other string.

How can I extract some parts of a string using a regex pattern?

Comment: Can you provide more details, perhaps an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *matching* that you are looking for. The `Regex.Match` and `Regex.Matches` methods use a regular expression to find one or several parts of a string, and returns a `Match` or `MatchCollection` with the result.

Example:

```
string input = "Some string with 123 numbers in it. Yeah 456!";

MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+");
foreach (Match m in result) {
  Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
123
456
```

Comment: can I use regex for unicode charachters (no english) ?

Comment: Yes, you can. The `\d` code for example matches digits in any language, not just arabic digits (0-9).